# Is it legal to ask for money to send a link to another website?

Tags: copyright

I want to make a website with some kind of "private subscription" system, where the subscribers will have access to the "mentor's choice" of mobile games, linking to their corresponding website (Google Play, Amazon shop, etc) after writing a small review of it.

Comment: Why would it be illegal to have a paywalled game review website?

Comment: @Philipp I don't know. Sometimes the law surprises me in some weird ways xD I don't see any problem, but better to ask just in case I get in a big trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be legal. A description or review of a copyrighted work is not a derivative work nor an infringement, unless it in fact copies an excessive amount of the original work. Otherwise such publications as the *New York Review of Books* could not exist. Therefore it is legal to charge for it. Whether enough people would pay to make it economical feasible is a different question, of course.